# Custom tag paragraph beak in Docusign Template

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently using sandbox Docusign Template.I have got one problem, I want paragraph break if signer type long text.This text field is custom.Like flowing:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHurR.png)

In the above sample second field  signer type long Text break to another line .
Is its possible using Docusign Template.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to specify a single DocuSign field (tab) that will start on line #1 (right-justified) and continue on line #2 (left-justified), as your screenshot shows. To use this part of your form with DocuSign, I'd suggest that you modify your underlying document such that the blank line for the second field appears all on one line (rather than spanning 2 lines).

Answer (score 0):

You can format the text tab by mentioning how many lines it can have and how many characters in each line it should have. So when signer starts typing DS will automatically do the line break, but as Kim suggested you need to change base document so that the text does not overlap on some other document text. You can adjust the text tab settings using [image: Line Breaks]